# How to use abstract class of table view data sources in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am using abstract class of `UITableView` `data source` and `delegate` and I want to use same `data sources` and `delegates` to another view controller having `UITableView` with different array of data. Is there any solution that how can I show data by using same `data sources` and `delegates` without `override` concept. My sample code of abstract class is on below:

```
import UIKit

class AbstractClass: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

    let animals: [String] = ["Horse", "Cow", "Camel", "Sheep", "Goat"]

    @IBOutlet var tableview: UITableView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableview.rowHeight = 44;

        //MARK: Register table view cell
        tableview.delegate = self
        tableview.dataSource = self
        tableview.register(UINib(nibName: "TableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "TableViewCell")


        // MARK: Navigation Bar Items
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem  = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Next", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(buttonAction1))

        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem  = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Next", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(buttonAction2))


    }

    // MARK: Table View Data Sources

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return self.animals.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let Cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
        Cell.backgroundColor = .black
        Cell.welcomeLbl.text = animals[indexPath.row]
        Cell.welcomeLbl.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        return Cell
    }


    // MARK: Table View Delegates
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 44
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }

    // MARK: Navigation button actions
    @objc func buttonAction1(){

        let navigationController1 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController") as? SecondViewController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(navigationController1!, animated: true)

    }

    @objc func buttonAction2(){

        let navigationController2 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ThirdViewController") as? ThirdViewController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(navigationController2!, animated: true)

    }
}
```

Comment: Read this article. https://medium.cobeisfresh.com/a-reusable-uitableviewdatasource-in-swift-e74d76bdda5f